# Is it possible to context.Add(object) in asynchronous Timer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dbcontext

i'm working on C# ASP.net and in need to create an object in my database through a asynchronous Timer.

My timer :

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Response response = new Response(tweet.Id, 1128199274838282240);

    _context.Add(response);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When i call it :

```
Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);

timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

and i give the context though the constructor when i create my class from the controller :

```
    private readonly cardsagainsttwitterContext _context;

    public GameManager(cardsagainsttwitterContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

And of course, i get this error because the context doesn't exist anymore :
- System.InvalidOperationException : 'An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'

So, is it possible to do this or neither ?
Thank for reading !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A context shall exist within a timelife, and usually in a web application it's (with all my recommendations) the request timelife itself or a shorter one, like transient.

If the timer starts after 60 seconds it would not have the request context, because the request it's done (I assume...) and the db context is disposed within its timelife.

Try to instantiate another context inside the timer event, and use it to save your response:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Response response = new Response(tweet.Id, 1128199274838282240);
    using(var timerContext=new cardsagainsttwitterContext())
    {
        timerContext.Add(response);
        timerContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```